# How to enable hairpin NAT between docker containers using bridge network

Tags: networking, docker, nat

We have 2 docker containers running on the same host using `bridge` network (`host` network isn't an option due to port conflicts).

- Container B is listening on port `9000` which is a service open on the host IP and forwarded to container B
- Container A cannot connect to `HOST.IP:9000`, it can connect to `172.17.0.6.:9000` (the internal IP of Container B), but that's a dynamic IP we don't want to track
- [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat) suggests that a `MASQUERADE` rule needs to be added to `iptables` to enable hairpin NAT, however, this is configured per port and thus is not portable. Changes to the host environment are undesirable from a maintainability perspective.

Is there a way to access Container B from Container A without changing the host configuration or knowing Container A's dynamic IP?

I see the following options when running `docker network inspect bridge`:

```
       "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
```

I see this suspicious looking setting on the container when running `docker inspect CONTAINER-NAME`:

```
       "NetworkSettings": {
            "HairpinMode": false,
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create [user-defined bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge), connect both containers to this network and use container name to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to access Container B from Container A without changing the host configuration or knowing Container A's dynamic IP?

The easiest and the recommended way is to create a [user-defined network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) and connect the containers to this network. With this, you'll be able to connect to container A from container B (or vice-versa) using the container name.

> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.
> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.

You can create the network and connect using the below commands:

```bash
docker network create <net-name>
docker network connect <net-name> <container-name>
docker network connect <net-name> <container-name>
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, but to be clear this does not enable hairpin nat through the host, but that's because hairpin nat isn't possible without host-specific changes as discussed here: https://serverfault.com/a/557776/54903 - This answer is the best you can get with docker only.

Comment: @davidparks21 thanks for the link, that's a solid writeup there